# How do I unequip both spells from the favorites menu?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to unequip both spells from the Favorites menu, but it's just not working. I can unequip the spell that has the `L` symbol on it, but if I try the other spell all it does is toggle between `R` and `LR`.

Is this a bug? I can't seem to remove all spells from both hands. This is for the **PC version of the game.**

Edit: Almost the new year's and this is still an issue. I can't fathom how this game won several game of the years despite being so broken. Has anything new been released to address this issue?

Edit 2: Middle of the year now. Hopefully there has been a patch solving this issue? I want to buy the game on Steam during the summer sale but would like to know beforehand if this has been solved correctly with no "work arounds".

Comment: As a workaround, I equip and un-equip my shield to get rid of the left-hand spell.

Comment: "Workaround"? :S That's not encouraging.

Comment: That sucks, I use the same workaround but it's so damn annoying, totally makes the game less intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

I can unequip both spells by clicking right once, to remove the off hand, then left to remove the main hand. Did no have problem with this.

Do understand that :

- You need to highlight the currently selected spell in the hand you want to remove
- Click with the mouse button corresponding to the hand you want to remove the spell from

Adding sequences:

- Spell () + <kbd>Mouse L</kbd> = Spell (L)
- Spell () + <kbd>Mouse R</kbd> = Spell (R)
- Spell (R) + <kbd>Mouse L</kbd> = Spell (R, L)
- Spell (L) + <kbd>Mouse R</kbd> = Spell (R, L)

Removing sequences:

- Spell (R, L) + <kbd>Mouse L</kbd> = Spell (R)
- Spell (R, L) + <kbd>Mouse R</kbd> = Spell (L)
- Spell (R) + <kbd>Mouse R</kbd> = Spell ()
- Spell (L) + <kbd>Mouse L</kbd> = Spell ()

Comment: Wait, are "Spell (R)" and "Spell (L)" reversed here?  Left-click for right hand and right-click for left hand keeps screwing me up.  >.<

Comment: Despite the upvotes this doesn't seem to work. :/

Comment: Depends on you keybindings of course. Here left button is main hand, right is off-hand. Its based on my FPS experience as left click main action, and left alternate action.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to counter the bug :

1. Put in your favorites a 2 hand sword and a shield.
2. First euqip the 2 hand sowrd then the shield.
3. The next thing you equip, can be for your right hand.

Good luck!